# "Cannot POST" Error on HTTP Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, postman

I'm new to firebase (and coding in general) and I'm trying to write a firebase cloud function that updates a document in a firestore collection, based on a HTTP trigger. I've deployed the function using the emulator in my terminal and tested it in postman.

The terminal response suggests that the cloud function ran successfully, but not only does the expected action not happen in firebase, i get a "404 not found" error and this response from postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

For context, this was the response from the firebase emulator in my terminal when i tried to test it locally:

```
    i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-uploadConsultation" 
    i  functions: Finished "us-central1-uploadConsultation" in 11.6975ms
```

Which seemed odd to me since the cloud function included some log messages which I expected would show up in the emulator.

This is the cloud function I'm trying to run:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// upload each landbot consultation to users' firestore collection

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/uploadConsultation', async(req,res) => {

    try{
        const consultationData = req.body;

        // Log the contents of the JSON file landbot has sent
        console.log('JSON Package sent from Landbot:', consultationData);

        // Identify the location of the "users" firestore collection
        const firestore = admin.firestore();
        const usersCollection = firestore.collection('users');

        // Extract userid and make a variable out of userid and another out of the remaining consultation data
        const {userid, ...consultation} = consultationData;

        // Check if users collection contains a document with the specified userid
        const userDocRef = usersCollection.doc(userid);
        const userDocSnapshot = await userDocRef.get();

        if (userDocSnapshot.exists) {

            // If the user id doc exists, add the remaining consultation data as a map field
            await userDocRef.update({consultation: consultationData});
            console.log('Added consultation data to user collection document:', );

        } else {

            // If user id doc doesn't exist, show error message
            console.log('There is no document in the users collection with that userid');
            res.status(422).send('No user exists with this userid');
        }
    } catch(error) {

        //handle errors using logs and sending error responses to landbot
        console.error('Error uploading consultation data');
        res.status(500).send('Error uploading consultation data to firestore');
    }
});
```

This is the http trigger url i was given in my terminal (i masked the projectid for privacy purposes):

```
    ✔  functions[us-central1-uploadConsultation]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/uche-hq/us-central1/uploadConsultation).`
```

And this is the url I used to test it in postman.

```
    "http://127.0.0.1:5001/uche-hq/us-central1/uploadConsultation" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email": "test@gmail.com","userid": "ofAkmWfs73OlRLvlsZ5m9nC1t5t1","answers": {"@me_minime": "Me","@hair_challenges": "Dry hair, Breakage","@current_state_of_hair": "Natural","@curl_type": "Type 4C","@porosity": "Low","@strandthickness": "Very coarse","@back_thickness": null,"@crown_thickness": null,"@edge_thickness": null,"@general_thickness": null,"@scalp_condition": "Psoriasis, Seborrheic Dermatitis, Itchy","@wash_day_frequency": "Once every 2 months","@style_for_recc": "Gelled style (e.g., wash + go / slicked back pony)","@hair_density": "Medium density","@back_density": null,"@crown_density": null,"@edge_density": null,"@rest_of_head_density": null,"@hair_length": "TWA","@reason_for_frequency": null,"@pregnant": "No","@hair_goals": "Longer hair, Curl definition, To retain moisture, Healthier scalp","@scalp_sensitivity": "Yes","@retailer": "Uche"}}'
```

In terms of what i've tried so far:

- I've checked that the url in postman matches the url from my terminal
- I've confirmed that the JSON formatting is correct
- and I looked over the function itself to make sure there aren't any issues.

When i googled / asked chatgpt, they said a "Cannot POST /" error typically suggests that the endpoint you're trying to access doesn't exist or isn't properly configured. But since i've triple checked the url, i don't know what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Two things. 1) That cloudfunctions.net URL is not for the emulator.  That's when you fully deploy it.  You don't have to deploy a function to run it in the emulator.  Your emulator will give you a different URL - please share the exact output from the emulator when it prints the URL for the function.  2) Where is your index.js that names and exports the function using onRequest so that Firebase knows about it.  An express app alone is not going to work at all.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense to you, I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#using_existing_express_or_flask_apps) to make a very simple express app work before adding code to it.  Get the function to run first, then add the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for catching that! I just updated my post with the exact emulator output and the exact http trigger. My index.js is saved in a folder with this structure: Firebase>functions>index.js (this functions folder also contains a node_modules folder and package.json and package-lock.json files). I also checked the package.json and these are the dependencies it contains:   

"dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^3.0.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },

Comment: I hear you on reviewing the docs and starting with something simpler, but still curious if there's something obvious i'm getting wrong. thank you!

Comment: Without a call to onRequest to register a function and export it with a name, nothing will work.  I don't see that here.